# Trying to do a simple GET HTTP request on the Facebook API with rest_client but it's not accepting the url, even though the URL works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I'm trying to get the data at this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=(my access token)
```

When I go to this address in a browser, it works. But I'm trying to use the [rest-client](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) gem in Ruby on Rails like this:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=' + access_token
result = RestClient.get url
p result
```

But I get this error message:

```
URI::InvalidURIError in AuthenticationsController#index
bad URI(is not URI?): https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=(my access token)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Could it have something to do with the format of the access_token? I've left it out in the code above, but this is the format it's in:

```
1xxx
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `access_token`:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=' + URI.escape(access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = RestClient.get 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed', :params => {:access_token => access_token }
```

You should do something like this

Comment: Can you explain why you think this will work when the OP's code doesn't?

Comment: Sorry, by 'OP' I meant the original question. Answers are more useful if you explain the thinking behind them.